# "CC" kaj "BCC" en Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests, information-technology

Ĉu mallongigoj kiel "CC" kaj "BCC" por "carbon copy" kaj "blind carbon copy" ekzistas en Esperanto? Ĉu oni uzas "tk" kaj "btk" por "trakopio" kaj "blinda trakopio"?

Comment: Kontrolu tiujn ĉi ligilojn kun la tradukoj en pluraj lingvoj ([cc:](https://transvision.mozfr.org/string/?entity=mail/chrome/messenger/messengercompose/messengercompose.dtd:ccAddr.label&repo=gecko_strings) kaj [bcc:](https://transvision.mozfr.org/string/?entity=mail/chrome/messenger/messengercompose/messengercompose.dtd:bccAddr.label&repo=gecko_strings)) kaj vi vidos ke pluraj teamoj decidis uzi la formon tutan, ĉar tiuj mallongigoj estas rekoneblaj ĉefe en la angla, sed ne nepre en aliaj lingvoj.

Answer (score 1):

La termino [karbopapero](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karbopapero) aŭ trakopia papero indikas specialan paperon oni uzis por fari kopiojn. Trakopio aŭ angle "carbon copy" estis kopio, kiun oni atingis per karbopapero. Por kopio nuntempe sufiĉas… "kopio" aŭ se vi volas precizigi "kopio de mesaĝo". Notu, ke multaj ne eĉ scias, kio estas karbopapero.

"Blind carbon copy" signifas kopion, kiu estas kaŝita for de aliaj, do "kaŝkopio" aŭ "kaŝita kopio" laŭ [Komputeko](https://komputeko.net/index_eo.php?vorto=carbon%20copy).

Comment: @EduardoTrápani, mi ne komprenas vian komenton, ĉar mi ne uzis tiujn mallongigojn en mia respondo.

Comment: mi maltrafis, pardonu. Mi jam estis verkinta la respondon kaj mi vidis ke la via ĝustis, mi do voĉdonis por ĝi kaj decidis aldoni mian respondon kiel komenton, kun la celo subteni vin. Mi movos la komenton al la demando, kien mi estus devinta meti ĝin komence.